# Oracle Listener utility and batch file

Tags: oracle

I have 03 listener on same database server. The listeners are: listener_cympp1(1522), listener_cymap1 (1523), listener_cympd1 (1524)
How can I  change name of listener log by batch file automaticall when the log is over 100 MB?
Which syntax can I use to set the listener name in this command? First executing "lsnrctl set current_listener listener_cympp1" doesn't help.

kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want rotate the listener log files with 100MB size log files. In addition, you request of explicitly specifying the log file name of each listener.

You can perform this without the need of a batch or shell script. The listener can be configured to do the log rotate based on size and number of files.

You can find all relevant information on Oracle documentation for the listener configuration parameters [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/troublestng.htm#i435787).

The parameters of interest are:

- TRACE_DIRECTORY_listener_name
- TRACE_FILE_listener_name
- TRACE_FILELEN_listener_name
- TRACE_FILENO_listener_name

You can set the parameter values per listener.

Comment: Thanks Costas Loizou! Your solution just apply for trace file, right? But, i want to rotate Listener Log files. My database is very active, after 2 year, the Listener.log maybe is over 4 GB. And I want to schedule by batch script to reduce Listener.log file for all database instance.